# Reverse double turnstile in Mathjax/Wordpress

Tags: mathjax, logic

I'm trying to make a reverse double turnstile on my wordpress site. I do have Mathjax installed. I've tried using `$\leftmodels$` and `$\Dashv$`, but neither of those work. I **am** able to make the regular double turnstile using `$\models$`. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current MathJax version [doesn't seem to provide](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-dev/blob/master/MML-entities/MJ-TeX-Unicode.txt) that symbol in form of a (La)TeX macro.

Using the MathJax [HTML extension](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.7-latest/tex.html#html) you can create a mirrored `\vDash` symbol from the original one:

```
$A\vDash B \quad
 B\mathbin{\style{display: inline-block; transform: scaleX(-1)}{\vDash}}A$
```

renders as

> [image]

Note the `\mathbin{...}` to convert the new box back into a binary operator for proper spacing around the symbol.

Alternatively, you can use the MathML entity `&Dashv;` (U+2AE4) to get a Unicode representation of that symbol.

Comment: Thank you for this! The only draw back is that `&Dashv;` is a different size than `$\models$`. So it doesn't look good using them together. I guess instead of using `$\models$`, I will use `&vDash;`. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Skull-Face Please see the update how to remedy the size problem

Comment: This works great! Thanks again!